# How to copy_to_user a string and use offp in a Linux Kernel read function

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, device

Declared:

```
static char status[128] = "off\0";
```

and implemented a `read` function:

```
static ssize_t read_proc(struct file *filep, char __user *buf,
                    size_t len, loff_t *offp)
{
    ssize_t cnt = strlen(status), ret;

    ret = copy_to_user(buf, status, cnt);
    *offp += cnt;
    return cnt;
}
```

- How do I take into account the `offp`?
- currently it prints endless the `status` to screen

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "it prints endlessly"?

Comment: @MichaelBurr

offoffoffoffoffoffoffoffoffoff .......

Comment: You'll have to check and account for the passed in offp. If the offset is larger than you string, you don't want to copy the string again. Note that the [seqfile](http://kernelnewbies.org/Documents/SeqFileHowTo) API offers a much easier way for e.g. creating /proc files. (See e.g. fs/proc/version.c for an example

Comment: You really need to explain more of the situation - how is the buffer being used by whatever code is consuming it? What is calling this function (i'm guessing you're using it to back a file descriptor as opened to your device). With the way you've written it, what else would it do? You're only copying the bytes ['o', 'f', 'f'] into the buffer, and presumably this is being used to back a file. You never return 0 bytes from a read, so if this is being used to serve a file descriptor, then of course the user-land program is just going to read "offoffoffoff".

Comment: If you want the user-land program to stop reading, then you need to return 0 at some point. Since `offp` tells you how many bytes you've written already, just return zero if `*offp => cnt`.

Comment: And you still need to think about whether or not you want to copy the null-terminator, because you're not, since `strlen("off")` returns 3, and so does `strlen("off\0")` and `strlen("off\0\0")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks the guys comments here I came up with the following implementation, which I believe is the right way to use `offp`:

```
static ssize_t read_proc(struct file *filep, char __user *buf,
                    size_t len, loff_t *offp)
{

    ssize_t cnt = strlen(status), ret;

    /* ret contains the amount of chare wasn't successfully written to `buf` */
    ret = copy_to_user(buf, status, cnt);
    *offp += cnt - ret;

    /* Making sure there are no left bytes of data to send user */
    if (*offp > cnt)
         return 0;
    else
         return cnt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your read_proc() will not stop reading until the function returns "0" or error. I believe you need to modify your read_proc to have this logic.

Answer (score 1):

To understand the return value from `read` let me quote from `Linux Device Drivers 3rd edition`:

```
The return value for read is interpreted by the calling application program:

    If the value equals the count argument passed to the read system call, the requested number of bytes has been transferred. This is the optimal case.

    If the value is positive, but smaller than count, only part of the data has been transferred. This may happen for a number of reasons, depending on the device. Most often, the application program retries the read. For instance, if you read using the fread function, the library function reissues the system call until completion of the requested data transfer.

    If the value is 0, end-of-file was reached (and no data was read).

    A negative value means there was an error. The value specifies what the error was, according to <linux/errno.h>. Typical values returned on error include -EINTR (interrupted system call) or -EFAULT (bad address).
```

So in short You need to always update `offp` and check on it's value before you start reading, and `return 0` if it already passed your data length, and in case of partial reads return the number of bytes read, you will update the `offp` in this case so the next call to read will result to returning 0 if you passed the length of data.

```
static ssize_t read_proc(struct file *filep, char __user *buf,
                size_t len, loff_t *offp)
{
    size_t count = len, status_length = strlen(status);
    ssize_t retval = 0;
    unsigned long ret = 0;

    if (*offp >= status_length)
        goto out;
    if (*offp + len > status_length)
        count = status_length - *offp;

    /* ret contains the amount of chars wasn't successfully written to `buf` */
    ret = copy_to_user(buf, status, count);
    *offp += count - ret;
    retval = count - ret;

out:
    return retval;
}
```

References:

- [Linux Device Drivers 3rd edition](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) - Chapter 3